# dayjs is not converting timezones properly

Tags: javascript, dayjs

I'm trying to convert a date from my local time (Taipei UTC+8) to Los Angeles ( UTC-7)
however dayjs conversion seems to be completely off :

```
dayjs("2020-09-21 20:30").tz("Asia/Taipei")
```

this results in **Tue Sep 22 2020 05:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)** but it should have been
**Mon Sep 21 2020 02:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)**

any idea what's going on?

Comment: Please read the Day.js documentation about string parsing and "Parsing in Zone".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I fixed using `utc` first and then format on local timezone

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc'
import tz from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone'

dayjs.extend(utc)
dayjs.extend(tz)

const timeZone = dayjs.tz.guess()
dayjs.utc(dateToConvert).tz(timeZone)
```

Comment: THIS is the fix.

Comment: What is `utcDate`?

Comment: @Abdull date which should be converted to desired tz

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
dayjs.extend(utc)
dayjs.extend(timezone)
dayjs("2020-09-21 20:30").tz("Asia/Taipei")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc'
import tz from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone'

dayjs.extend(utc)
dayjs.extend(tz)    

dayjs("2020-09-21 20:30").tz("Asia/Taipei").local().toDate();

dayjs("2020-09-21 20:30").tz("Asia/Taipei").local().toDate().toLocaleString();
```

`.toString()` and `.toISOString()` seem to always print the original date, before the timezone conversion, which may cause some confusion. `toDate().toLocaleString()` works.

Comment: This is the real answer. By not setting `.local().toDate()` it does not convert the date to the selected timezone. Really strange approach they took with that.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed it by adding .local() after dayjs("2020-09-21 20:30").tz("Asia/Taipei").local()

Answer (score 2):

I'm using latest version of dayjs - 1.11.1 and react native v0.66.4.
When I write:

```
dayjs("2020-09-21 20:30").tz("Asia/Taipei")
```

I get null as result. Does anybody have that problem?

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Comment: check this https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/1377#issuecomment-775941749

Answer (score 2):

Without including any plugin like `utc`, `timezone` you can easily format utc date and pass it into dayjs like below:

```
const utcTimestamp = 1668414677538;
const utcFormat = dayjs(utcTimestamp).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss+00:00');
console.log(dayjs(utcFormat).format('DD MMM, hh:mm a'));
```

It will do the trick