# Dayjs creating date in specific timezone

Tags: javascript, frontend, dayjs

I was developing a timetable using dayjs. I would like to set the timetable to show something likes UTC-9 date regardless of user's local time. I tried with dayjs's timezone and utc mode. Both change the time to the correct time but not the date. If I set PC time to other date, dayjs still showing that date instead of UTC-9 date. Thanks.

Comment: Look at UTC offset,this dependent on UTC plugin to work:https://day.js.org/docs/en/manipulate/utc-offset

Comment: @Oleg I tried with utc offset. It only changed the time to correct utc-offset but not the date. For example, let say current utc+10 is Jun 6, I want to show Jun 6 even the user's local time in his computer is Jun 5.

Comment: did you try like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64006977/dayjs-is-not-converting-timezones-properly

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There is a nice example in the day.js documentation itself.

```
dayjs.extend(utc)
dayjs.extend(timezone)

dayjs.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York")

dayjs("2014-06-01 12:00").tz("America/New_York")
```

[day.js timezone documentation](https://day.js.org/docs/en/timezone/timezone)

Comment: Those two ways of creating a date are NOT equivalent. Presenting them this way seems to imply either is acceptable. However, the first will create a date in the given timezone, the second will create a date in UTC, then _convert_ that date to the given timezone. The result of those two operations will not be the same.