# How can I parse a string to a time without taking timezone into account at all?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, dayjs

I want to take an input string like `'2024-08-24T20:00:00-04:00'` (8pm in Boston MA), feed it to `dayjs` so that it will be formatted as *the exact same time*.

The time format I'm using is `dayjs(startTimeStr).format('YYYY-MM-DD H:mm')`, which is giving me `'2024-08-25 1:00'` but the actual format isn't important. What's important is that I want it to parse it without changing timezones.

I'm in Boston but I've set my computer's time zone to London. This is to simulate the behavior of my deployed Remix server, which appears to be on GMT, since when I use my actual time zone I can't reproduce the production bug locally.

I've tried using `dayjs.tz` but it simply results in `0:00` instead of `1:00`. I'm guessing the difference of *only one hour* has to do with daylight savings time.

```
dayjs.extend(timezone)
// ...
const startTimeStr = '2024-08-24T20:00:00-04:00'
const id = dayjs.tz(startTimeStr, 'America/New_York').format('YYYY-MM-DD H:mm') // '2024-08-25 1:00'
```

What I want is simply for supply a date and time as a string, and get a dayjs object that is *simply that time*, with no Time Zone awareness, not even any Daylight Savings awareness!

In other words, parsing a string from format X to a date and back to format X should yield the exact original string, regardless of whether I'm parsing in June or January, regardless of whether I'm parsing in Boston or London.

Why is this so hard!?!?!?

Comment: One reason it's hard is that you're starting from a date/time format that is explicitly intended to include time zone information.

Comment: There is no such thing as "no timezone". Do you mean "the local timezone of whatever software is parsing your code"?

Comment: try `dayjs(startTimeStr).tz('America/New_York')...`  See the comment under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72513543/535480) for the difference.

Comment: @JohannesH. No, that is expressly what it needs to not be. It needs to be the same clock-time no matter where it’s parsed. The time always represents a time in Boston. And needs to always be interpreted as the time as written in Boston. (Which, for what it’s worth, is the same time zone as New York). If the string indicates 8/24/24 8pm then no matter where you parse it you should get 8/24/24 8pm.

Comment: @James I think that's the answer, and thank you for pointing to that link! I had thought they were equivalent as well!

Comment: @JonathanTuzman Ok, I got that. YOur question is a bit misleading then in its wording, as what you want is the code to actually be aware of the timezone included in the date, not be unaware of any timezones.

Comment: It's possible, it's just that dayjs is missing this feature. See the answer in marked duplicate for the short version.   For the longer version, see https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/651.

Comment: Also recognize that your question is in conflict with itself - you can't simultaneously take the offset into account while parsing and also have no awareness of time zone offset.  I think what you actually mean is that you want the offset to be _retained_, rather than just used for conversion to UTC or local time.  The dup answer will show you how to do that.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint thank you, it is about the offset being retained regardless of the local time zone. Hopefully I'll never need to ask this again but thank you for a much clearer way to say what I'm asking. :)

Comment: The question has been closed, but with some experimentation it seems like an important thing I missed is that you want to specify the TZ you're *starting* in as well. Then it becomes more clear, and the simple solution is `dayjs('02-05-21 02:33 PM MST').tz('MST').format(FMT)`. The argument to dayjs supplies the "input timezone" and the `.tz` call after supplies the same exact "output" timezone. As long as they're both the same it will always work. (though my input format is stricter than the `.tz` argument; the latter can take, say, `'Japan'` or `'America/New_York'` but the former cannot)